# Call Arguments of Function inside Function / R language

Tags: r, function

I have a function:

```
func <- function (x)
{
  arguments <- match.call()
  return(arguments)
}
```

1) If I call my function with specifying argument in the call:

```
func("value")
```

I get:

```
func(x = "value")
```

2) If I call my function by passing a variable:

```
my_variable <-"value"
func(my_variable)
```

I get:

```
func(x = my_variable)
```

Why is the first and the second result different?
Can I somehow get in the second call "func(x = "value")"?

I'm thinking my problem is that the Environment inside a function simply doesn't contain values if they were passed by variables. The Environment contains only names of variables for further lookup. Is there a way to follow such reference and get value from inside a function?

Comment: The call is not evaluated, so how should `my_variable` be substituted by `"value"`? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, when you pass `my_variable` as formal argument `x` into a function, the value of `my_variable` will only be retrieved when the function tries to read `x` (if it does not use `x`, `my_variable` will not be read at all). The same applies when you pass more complicated arguments, such as `func(x = compute_my_variable())` -- the call to `compute_my_variable` will take place when `func` tries to read `x` (this is referred to as lazy evaluation).

Given lazy evaluation, what you are trying to do is not well defined because of side effects - in which order would you like to evaluate the arguments? Which arguments would you like to evaluate at all? (note a function can just take an expression for its argument using `substitute`, but not evaluate it). As a side effect, `compute_my_variable` could modify something that would impact the result of another argument of `func`. This can happen even when you only passed variables and constants as arguments (function `func` could modify some of the variables that will be later read, or even reading a variable such as `my_variable` could trigger code that would modify some of the variables that will be read later, e.g. with active bindings or delayed assignment).

So, if all you want to do is to log how a function was called, you can use `sys.call` (or `match.call` but that indeed expands argument names, etc). If you wanted a more complete stacktrace, you can use e.g. `traceback(1)`.

If for some reason you really wanted *values* of all arguments, say as if they were all read in the order of `match.call`, which is the order in which they are declared, you can do it using eval (returns them as list):

```
lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], eval)
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you simply

```
return paste('func(x =', x, ')')
```

Comment: I can but I didn't want to code all possible variables by hand.
My functions is used in the call to web-API with 15+ possible parametrs.

Comment: but you just want a string, don't you? can't you still use the paste function like this:

Comment: sorry, I didn't finish the comment: `l= as.list(match.call())[-1]; return(paste('func(, paste(names(l), l, sep=' = ', collapse=', '), ')'))`